# Basic NumPy array replacement

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a rather basic question about the NumPy module in Python 2, particularly the version on trinket.io.  I do not see how to replace values in a multidimensional array several layers in, regardless of the method.  Here is an example:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
a[0] = 0

print a

a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
a[0][0] = a[1][0] = 0

print a
```

Result:

```
array([0, 2, 3], '<class 'int'>')
array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], '<class 'int'>')
```

I need the ability to change individual values, my specific code being:

```
a = numpy.empty(shape = (8,8,2),dtype = str)

for row in range(a.shape[0]):
  for column in range(a.shape[1]):
    a[row][column][1] = 'a'
```

Thank you for your time and any help provided.

Comment: Your code works for me and prints the expected results `[0 2 3]` and `[[0 2 3], [0 2 3]]`. What version of Python and numpy are you using?

Comment: An unspecified version of python 2 and numpy on trinket.io, https://trinket.io/library/trinkets/create?lang=python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change individual values you can simply do something like:

```
a[1,2] = 'b'
```

If you want to change all the array, you can do:

```
a[:,:] = 'c'
```

Use commas (`array[a,b]`) instead of (`array[a][b]`)

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a ValueError being raised if I just try to access the value with your method, ex:

    import numpy

    a = numpy.empty(shape = (8,8,2),dtype = str)

    print a[0,0,0]

Result:

    ValueError: Tuple must contain values for all dimensions on line 5 in main.py

Answer (score 0):

With numpy version `1.11.0`, I get

```
[[0 2 3]
 [0 2 3]]
```

When I run your code.  I guess your numpy version is newer and better.

As user3408085 said, the correct thing is to go `a[0,0] = 0` to change one element or `a[:,0]=0` if your actually want to zero the entire first column.

The reason `a[0][0]=0` does not modify a (at least in your version of numpy) is that a[0] is a new array.  If break down your command `a[0][0]=0` into 2 lines:

```
b=a[0]
b[0]=0
```

Then the fact that this modifies a is counterintuitive.

Comment: `a[0]` is a view of the first row of matrix `a`. It is **not copied**, and I don't think this has been the case for any numpy version. You can check this easily with `c = a[0]; c[1] = 99; print a`